# How can I download an image in S3 as a file Typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Although I would like to be able to download multiple files at once from a bucket, I have so far found out that it is only possible to download one at a time using the getObject function. That is what I have been using. However, I have no idea how to convert the response into a file that represents an image.

```
  getOBject(key: S3.ObjectKey) {
    this.s3.getObject(
      { Bucket: environment.aws.Bucket, Key: key },
      (error, data) => {
        if (error != null) {
          console.log('Failed to retrieve an object: ' + error);
        } else {
          console.log('Loaded ' + data.ContentLength + ' bytes');
          // What do I do here with data to convert it to a File.
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: are you just wanting the base64 content to display an image?

Comment: I would like to read exif data from my images and for that I need them as files.

Comment: You should use a blob to handle binary objects